# Mix queries together

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I've made a chat script in ColdFusion that uses different MySQL tables. One is where the conversation is stored, and the other one is the one that defines who started the conversation and who received it.

Now, I've made a script that allows you to chat together with someone. When sending a message, it adds a row into the MySQL table with a timestamp, the message id, the user id that sended the message and the message itself. The whole conversation is displayed with this code:

```
// Get all conversations started by the user that is signed in 
<cfquery name = "Friendship" datasource = "#DSN#">
    SELECT *
    FROM  `conversations`
    WHERE  `user_one` LIKE  '#user.id#'
    ORDER BY  `conversations`.`lastmessage` DESC
</cfquery>

// Get all conversations started by others but receiver is the user that is signed  in                                                                                  
<cfquery name = "FriendshipBack" datasource = "#DSN#">
    SELECT *
    FROM  `conversations`
    WHERE  `user_two` LIKE  <cfqueryparam value="#user.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    ORDER BY  `conversations`.`lastmessage` DESC
</cfquery>


// OUTPUT - conversations that I began
<cfoutput query="Friendship">
    // This code translates a user id into a name
    <cfquery name = "FriendshipToUsername" datasource = "#DSN#">
        SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE id = '#user_two#'
    </cfquery>

    <cfif IsDefined("FriendshipToUsername.username")>
        <cfif IsDefined('URL.chat') and URL.chat neq "">
        </cfif>                

       // Display username 
      <h3>#FriendshipToUsername.username#</h3>
    </cfif>

</cfoutput>

/// OUTPUT - conversations that I received
<cfoutput query="FriendshipBack">
    // This query translates a user id into a name
    <cfquery name = "FriendshipToUsernameBack" datasource = "#DSN#">
        SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="#user_one#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    </cfquery>

    <cfif IsDefined('URL.chat') and URL.chat neq "">
    </cfif>                
    // Display username 

    <h3>#FriendshipToUsernameBack.username</h3>
</cfoutput>
```

At this moment the chat list is seperated into two categories: one is a list where the signed in user started the conversation, the other one is where the signed in user received a conversation from someone else. The problem is, that I don't want it to display it that way, so I want to mix both lists together and list them all based on the timestamp (from newest to oldest)

At this moment the chat list is seperated into two categories: one is a list where the signed in user started the conversation, the other one is where the signed in user received a conversation from someone else. The problem is, that I don't want it to display it that way, so I want to mix both lists together and list them all based on the timestamp (from newest to oldest)

Is there any way to achieve this?

*I know that my code is exploitable, but this is still WIP*

Comment: Can you update your post with the relevant query and output code? If you remove the extra white space and unrelated html it is a reasonable enough size to post here.

Comment: I've removed unrelated HTML from the code and added it to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this moment the chat list is seperated into two categories: one is
>   a list where the signed in user started the conversation, the other
>   one is where the signed in user received a conversation from someone
>   else.

Then simply query the table where *either* of those conditions are true, and sort the records by timestamp.  (Also, as mentioned on another thread, when searching for an *exact* match the correct operator is equals ie `=`, not `LIKE`).

```
  ...
  WHERE  conversations.user_one = <cfqueryparam value="#user.id#" 
                                           cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
  OR     conversations.user_two = <cfqueryparam value="#user.id#" 
                                           cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
  ORDER BY  conversations.lastmessage DESC
```

> This code translates a user id into a name

Do not query within a loop, if you can avoid it. It adds a lot of unnecessary overhead. The proper way to retrieve the related columns is adding a [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to your query. Since you must join to the `user` table multiple times (to get both names) use an `alias` to differentiate:

```
  SELECT conversations.user_one
         , conversations.user_two
         , u1.username AS userNameOne
         , u2.username AS userNameTwo
         , ... 
  FROM   conversations 
            JOIN users u1 INNER JOIN u1.id = conversations.user_one
            JOIN users u2 INNER JOIN u2.id = conversations.user_two
  WHERE  ...
```

Comment: I can't get to make this work. I'm really new to ColdFusion so i don't have any experience with it. Could you tell me what queries i need to change?

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with ColdFusion. It is all SQL. *Re: I can't get to make this work* Second, post what you have tried (ie the code that isn't working) and tell us the results. We cannot help you fix the query, if we cannot see it. *tell me what queries i need to change* To be a bit blunt, it does not do much good to just "give" you code you do not understand ;-)

Comment: My suggestion would be to start simply. Query the conversations table with `WHERE` clause above. Check the results. Then go from there.

Comment: Thanks! That already did the trick. Still figuring out some other things, but thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a single union all query instead of two individual queries, you will be able to do so.

Comment: I already tried to do that, but I couldn't really figure it out how to.